# Voltage phasor problem in textbook wrong?

Tags: voltage, amplifier, gain

An example in my textbook gives this problem:

Find the phasor representation of vo = -5cos(2000πt+25°)

Answer: 5<-65°

Shouldn't it be 5<-155°? You subtract/add 180° to get the negative of cosine, not 90.

[image]

Comment: Sin and cos do not have phase shift of 180. You also got the gain wrong.

Comment: What would you say is the phasor representation of vo = -5cos(2000πt+0°)?

Comment: @Andyaka: 5<-180° or 5<180°

Comment: OK, what about -5 **sin** (2000πt+0°)?

Comment: @Andyaka ah I see I forgot about the sin-cos conversion, thank you. It's still confusing to me why they're using sin as the reference instead of cos since I was told that's the convention.

Comment: So, you have your answer?

Comment: @Andyaka -5sin(2000πt+0°) is 5<180° if we're using sin as the reference, or 5<90° if we're using cos as the reference. They're apparently using sin as the reference since they added 90° to the phasor for the vo.

Comment: The natural default is sine.